# Passing state to child component

Tags: react-native

**In the following React Native scenario, how can I pass the variable `userId` from the 'parent' component to the 'child' component?**

I have a 'parent' component like so:

```
export class UserProfileScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userId: 123,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <UserIntro />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And a 'child' component like so:

```
export class UserIntro extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Introduction for user {userId}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export class UserProfileScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userId: 123,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <UserIntro id={this.state.userId} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}


export class UserIntro extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Introduction for user {this.props.id}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: So it automatically binds any prop I pass in to `this.props`? That's awesome! Where can I read more about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass anything(JSON object,JSON Array,simple arrays,float and even function etc)  from parent to child using props. There is no limit of props number.

you can execute parent function from child as well using props

```
export class UserProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userId: 123
    };
  }

  getUpdatedUserID = updatedId => {
    this.setState({userId:updatedId});
    alert(updatedId);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <UserIntro id={this.state.userId} getUpdatedUserID={this.getUpdatedUserID} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class UserIntro extends React.Component {


  updateUserId=()=>
  {
    this.props.getUpdatedUserID((int)(this.props.id)+1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Introduction for user {this.props.id}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.updateUserId}  />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```